# $_GET value from <button>?

Tags: php, button, get

I'm working on trying to switch out a hidden input with a value set to a button with a value set in order to have more than one possible outcome from the same form.

```
echo "<button class='btn-mini btn' type='submit' formaction='inc/delete.php' value='" . $record['id'] . "'><i class='icon icon-remove'></i></button>";
```

Once, submitted I try to assign the value to a variable and dump it:

```
$getid = $_GET["id"];
var_dump('$getid');
```

But, I end up with this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\address-book\inc\delete.php on line 5
```

string(6) "$getid"

This there a different way to pull the value of a `<button>` verse that of a `<input>` using $_GET?

Comment: You call `$_GET['id']` but I don't see anything with the attribute `name="id"`

Comment: You want to fetch the value with the key "id" from your get array. So is the button id = "id" ?
And which method do you use in your form? GET or POST?

Comment: [PHP handles string literals with double and single quotes differently.](http://php.net/language.types.string) In your case, you don’t even need quotes: `var_dump($getid);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between using single quotes and double quotes.

Simple quote will not parse variables but, understand the input as 'string' only!

So, in essence:

suppose: your URL as : ?id=3

```
$getid = "hello world";
echo '$getid'; // O/P will be $getid
echo "$getid"; // O/P will be hello world
```

coming to your question, you need to define a `name` for anything that is submitted in the form:

```
echo "<button class='btn-mini btn' type='submit' formaction='inc/delete.php' value='" . $record['id'] . "'><i class='icon icon-remove'></i></button>";
```

should be:

```
echo "<button class='btn-mini btn' name='id' type='submit' formaction='inc/delete.php' value='" . $record['id'] . "'><i class='icon icon-remove'></i></button>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

A silly mistake missing the `name` tag.